# How can I create an atomic enum in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, atomic

Class `atomic` contains [atomic versions of many different variable types](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/#types). However, it doesn't contain an atomic enum type. Is there a way to use atomic enums or make my own? As far as I can tell, my only option is to either not use enums or use mutexes/semaphores to protect them.

Note: This [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=900965) I found mentions "std::atomic enum support", but I don't see any mention of an atomic enum type in the C++ Standard, so I'm not sure what that refers to.

Comment: The bug report you linked to clears itself up pretty neatly, I think: "don't use `<atomic>` before gcc version 4.7"

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can create an atomic enum like this:

```
#include <atomic>

enum Decision {stay,flee,dance};
std::atomic<Decision> emma_choice {stay}; // emma_choice is atomic
```

You can also do the same thing with enum classes:

```
#include <atomic>

enum class Decision {stay,flee,dance};
std::atomic<Decision> emma_choice {Decision::stay}; // emma_choice is atomic
```

Comment: Interesting as I had the equivalent of `emma_choice = Decision::stay` and it would fail. Changing it with `emma_choice { Decision::stay }` made it compile.

Comment: @AlexisWilke That's because the copy assignment operator is `delete`d for atomic types. If you did something like `emma_choice = Decision::stay`, then `Decision::stay` would first be implicitly converted to a `std::atomic<Decision>`, and then copied over, but that's not allowed for atomics. So, you have to explicitly call a constructor to initialize an atomic.

Comment: @Pacopenguin I believe this is no longer the case in C++17 due to mandatory copy elision https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision. Clang accepts it.

Answer (score 30):

The generic `atomic` template can be used for all trivially copyable types, including enumerations. Whether or not it's lock-free is up to the implementation; hopefully it will be, if the underlying integer type is.

Comment: ... and one can check so with [is_lock_free()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free)