# Is c++11 enum class thred safe?

Tags: c++11, enums, mutex

I wonder what happens if I don't lock an enum variable in the following writer-reader situation:

```
enum class Foo {One,Two,Three};
Foo foo = Foo::One;

// Thread A:
wait_for_something();
// no mutex lock
foo= Foo::Two;

// Thread B:
while(foo==Foo::One){
// no mutex lock
do_something();
}
```

I can think of sequences that in the middle of `do_something`, `foo` changes. This is not really important, I would like to know if there is any other issues with this lockless code?

Comment: enum has nothing to do with thread safety. its just a labelled constant values.

Comment: Check how to do [atomic enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756457/how-can-i-create-an-atomic-enum-in-c).

Comment: The behavior is exactly the same as with `int foo = 1;` and `while (foo == 1)` - namely, undefined; your code has a data race. Nothing related to thread safety changes when you replace an `int` with an `enum`.