# cannot able to create enum type as atomic

Tags: c++, enums, g++, atomic

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;    
typedef enum day{sun =0, mon, tue}day;    

int main() {
    atomic<day> a(sun);
    cout<<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code try to create a enum variable as atomic type. But i am getting the following error.

```
undefined reference to std::atomic<day>::operator day() const
```

Does atomic have no support for enum type? or any mistake in my syntax? I am using g++ compiler running on 32 bit ubuntu 12.0.4 machine. thank you.

Comment: There's no need for the C-idiomatic `typedef enum` in C++, although I doubt that's the issue here.

Comment: Which g++ version? I can only repro on Wandbox with GCC 4.6.

Comment: I'd say this is a compiler bug. `atomic` can be used for all plain old data types and that includes enumerations.

Comment: The non-specialized `atomic` base template isn't implemented until GCC 4.7.

Comment: How are you invoking your compiler? `atomic` was introduced in c++11 so make sure you're passing the `--std=c++11` or the `--std=c++0x` to `g++`

Comment: @AnthonyVallée-Dubois i am passing --std=c++0x to the compiler.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756457/how-can-i-create-an-atomic-enum-in-c

Answer (score 2):

I've compiled the same code with the online compiler that supports C++11 & C++14. I didn't get any issues.

`atomic` isn't available before C++11 standards.

For your reference: http://ideone.com/fork/Pe4gVt

Comment: what is the compiler you used? mine is g++ 4.6.3.